# Get host IP Address from within docker container

Tags: docker, virtualization, docker-container

Is it possible to get your native 'localhost' IP from within a docker container?
(example:)

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get host IP from within a Docker container but you can pass this as an environment variable.